# Fatal error : Cannot use [] for reading in very simple example

Tags: php

```
$fieldDefinitions = [
    'first_name' => ‌[]
]; // here it shows the error
```

I don't get what is wrong.

PHP 5.6

Comment: Can you update your question with the error. And what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I still don't understand, from your title you say _reading_, but you are not reading any value in your code.

Comment: You have an invisible character in there somewhere. Delete and retype it. When I copy/paste your code, I get `'first_name' => <200c>[]`

Comment: the code seems ok, not sure if this will help but when I copy/ paste your code there was a character before the square brakes. Just like @aynber mention and typed faster than me lol

Comment: As @aynber said, the same thing happened with me when pasting your code in 3v4l.org

Comment: Thank you all. It was that. I copied it from PHPStorm console. I was struggling with this. Shame on PHPStorm

Comment: I have download a plugin called Zero Width Character in PHPStorm that alerts this